# Multiprocessing on prime numbers function runs slower when only checking for odd numbers

Tags: python

I've been having an odd behavior in my code when checking for primes. for example

```
for j in range(3, int(i**0.5)+1, 2):
```

When using this and only checking for odd numbers, my processes take 0.7401000000000446 mins to complete with 10 million numbers.

meanwhile changing it back to this:

```
for j in range(2, int(i**0.5)+1, 1):
```

takes 0.3927166666666987 mins with also 10 million numbers.

what am i doing wrong? i thought going through odd numbers only would result in much faster processing but im getting different results.

here is the full code segment:

```
import time
import multiprocessing


def prime(i, processes, maxnum, primes):
    while maxnum >= i:
        f = False
        if i <= 1:
            i += processes
            continue
        else:
            for j in range(2, int(i**0.5)+1, 1):  # i think the bug is in the way [i] is given to processes.
                if i % j == 0:
                    i += processes
                    f = True
                    break
        if f:
            continue

        primes.append(i) # append if prime.
        # increment by number of processes, example: p1 (i =1) p2 (i=2) up to i = processes, then all jumps by num of processes, check for bugs
        i += processes


def test(i):
    print("process num: " + str(i))

def main():
    start = time.monotonic()
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    primes = manager.list()
    maxnum = 10000000
    processes = 16 * 2
    plist = []

    for i in range(1, processes + 1):

        plist.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=prime, args=(i, processes, maxnum, primes,)))

    [p.start() for p in plist]

    [p.join() for p in plist]

    print("time taken: " + str((time.monotonic() - start) / 60) + ' mins')
    print(plist)

    print(sorted(primes))  #unsure how long does the sorting takes


if __name__ == "__main__": # multiprocessing needs guarding. so all code goes into main i guess
    main()
```

Comment: For me in jupyter, using `%%timeit` all ones took `4.56 s ± 870 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` and odd ones took 
`3.64 s ± 783 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` which makes sense as odd ones take long time while even ones will be knocked out at 2

Comment: you have a cpu with 32 cores at hand? if not: it does not make sense to have more processes than cpu cores...